# Powershell Automation - Passing Password after executing a exe file

Tags: powershell

I working on automating the specific task using powershell and getting error while passing the password. Below is my task. Below are the tasks I need to automate.

1. Execute exe file (For ex: export.exe)
2. It will prompt for password twice (Enter your password and Reenter your password)
3. After Entering our password Twice, It will ask for confirmarion Yes or No: (I need to give 'Yes' or No to continue )

I tried automating the above first two steps. First I get the stored password in a file using the below command

```
$password = get-content C:\cred.txt | convertto-securestring
```

Then I tried executing the below commands in script

```
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $pass
Invoke-Expression "& `"C:\Program Files\XX\XX\bin\export.exe`""
```

But I dont know how to use the password from the file twice to continue the script. I am new to powershell. Please help me.

Comment: This is entirely going to depend on the EXE.  If the password were `Pa$$word`, how would you pass it to `export.exe` manually?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that your application will accept PowerShell's `PSCredential` object. More likely, you just have to pass plaintext password twice and then `Yes`.

Try this (assuming that `export.exe` is console application):

```
'Password', 'Password', 'Yes' | & 'C:\Program Files\XX\XX\bin\export.exe'
```

This will send 3 strings, separated by the newline (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) to the `export.exe`'s stdin.

Comment: I am getting the below error.

`export.exe : Error while getting password from User.`